# How to Search substring in Multiple columns using Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

following is my code to call the database to find the substring "ello".

```
String queryString = "from ContentItem where singerName = '%"+searchString+"%' OR  songName = '%"+searchString+"%'";
System.out.println(queryString);
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
return query.list();
```

the string output is

```
from ContentItem where singerName = '%ello%' OR songName = '%ello%'
```

it says Unexpected Token for %. How to make this possible to search substring inside those columns?

I'm working Hibernate inside Tapestry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the equals (=) operator does not work with wildcards. You need to use `like` (or ilike).

eg

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column like '%abc%';
```

[see this document](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) for more info.